# Too many open files error in one of kafka broker even when the limits are set to unlimited. Is the data too much?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a Kafka cluster of 5 brokers(r5.xlarge). Yesterday we started our production database snapshot using Debezium, which basically dumps the entire database in Kafka topics.
I could see that the CPU utilization never went above 30% in any of our brokers. Also, Network In bytes was around 350 Mbps at its peak.

Now sometime at midnight, one of our brokers failed because of too many open files exception even though I have set ulimit to unlimited in all our brokers. I don't understand what is becoming the bottleneck in this setup. Is it the number of brokers? or disk throughput? or network?

I have a few ideas :

1. Increase the number of brokers.
2. Using multiple data directories in multiple disks? Will that improve disk throughput?
3. Using topic compression.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the max open files limits set in /etc/security/limits.conf were not applicable to my running Kafka service. [Why so?](https://serverfault.com/questions/641899/ulimit-file-descriptor-limits-not-being-applied-for-particular-process)
To check the limits set for any process we can do

1. Find the process id of the process using `ps ax | grep kafka.Kafka`
2. cat /proc/{{process_id}}/limits | grep "Max open files"

For my Kafka process, it was set to the default value of 4096.

In order to increase this limit, I added a line 
`ulimit -n 1000000` just before starting the kafka process in the service file and things worked!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. I've added it to service file as:

    LimitNOFILE=100000